# publish_actions firing second permissions dialog

Tags: facebook, permissions, dialog

I have a Facebook app that posts to users profiles. 
I've changed the app to ask for publish_actions instead of publish_stream, but the request still appears on the second permissions dialog and looks just like the publish_stream permission. The app posts to the user's timeline, which I understand publish_actions supports. Is there something else I need to do to get the permission to appear on the first permissions dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

> Additionally publishing permissions such as publish_actions or publish_stream will prompt a second step in the Login dialog, which can cause fewer people to log in:

You will always get the second prompt when you ask for either of the permissions. It was long time ago when using `publish_actions` permission didn't cause a second dialog box as documented in this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/).